# Saying word "dinner" causes Actions to immediately quit

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We have an language learning Action, where the user can ask say anything they want. When they say "dinner", our Action immediately quits, without saying the cancel response.

We tried several other Actions and they all behave the same way.

Except Google Translate that says "Something went wrong".

Is there a way for our Action to react on "dinner" somehow?

Comment: That's a weird issue, and I can't seem to reproduce it myself.

Comment: I should've mentioned I see it on Smart Displays: Lenovo 10" and Google Hub

Comment: I just tried again on a Google Nest Hub and it correctly goes to the fallback intent.

Comment: @NickFelker I used Google Hub (1st generation), not Nest Hub.

Comment: Yeah the Google Home Hub is the same device as the Nest Hub. (Rebranding :| )

Answer (score -1):

I think you should make another intent where you can mention "dinner" as a training phrase. Then you can give a response against that training phrase. This might solve your problem.